# How to reset SVG color on second click

Tags: jquery, svg

I am using this to fill an svg on click :

```
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
```

which is the simplest way to have the color reset to default when a user clicks the button the second time?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to set the `fill` with a CSS class, then toggle that class on click:

```js
$('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
svg rect {
  fill: #CCC;
}
.foo {
  fill: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect id="color-my-svg" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:-**

```js
var change_color = 0;
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
if(change_color==0){
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
    change_color = 1;
    }
else{
jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "blue" });
    change_color = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful...

```
jQuery('#color-my-svg').on("click", function() {
  if(!jQuery(this)[0].hasAttribute('style')){
    jQuery('#color-my-svg').css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
  }
  else{
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is in the correct path, but weirdly it works on the reverse like it applies the fill color on second click instead of applying the color on the first click then resetting on the second click